# escaping the dollar sign

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have a line in my.cnf file

```
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
```

The following changes it to mysql3307 as expected.

```
sed -i 's/\/var\/lib\/mysql$/\/var\/lib\/mysql3307/' /etc/my.cnf
```

But if I have the following:

```
datadir = /var/lib/mysql/
```

Then the following does not change the path as expected:

```
sed -i 's/\/var\/lib\/mysql\/$/\/var\/lib\/mysql3307/' /etc/my.cnf
```

I want to change the path to mysql3307 where datadir is /var/lib/mysql (with or without /)

Update:

Here is the issue: 
Both the above commands works on one server and none of them works on another.

The following works as expected, but I need to add that $ to indicate the lines ending with mysql/

```
sed -i 's/\/var\/lib\/mysql\//\/var\/lib\/mysql3307/' /etc/my.cnf
```

Observed:

The carot sign ^ works as expected, but end of line sign $ does not. Any clue?

Update:

It seems to be working after using "dos2unix" command.

Comment: When using sed on strings with '/'s in them (eg file paths) you might want to use something else as the delimiter, like ':'. `sed -i 's:/var/lib/mysql$:/var/lib/mysql3307:' /etc/my.cnf` is a bit nicer to read :)

Comment: I'm not really sure what the problem is? I echoed your second example string into your second example sed and got `datadir = /var/lib/mysql3307`

Comment: Yes. The question is wrong. Actually none of them work on one server and both the commands work on another!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intent is to only change paths that have that specific directory, you need to be a bit trickier. You have to catch it at the end of a line without the trailing `/` and you also have to catch it everywhere it *has* the trailing `/` (end of line or not).

But you don't want to catch things like `/var/lib/mysqlplus` since that's a totally *different* directory.

Consider using extended regular expressions, and using a different separator character so you command doesn't look like sawteeth (`/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\`). With those changes, and a small modification to the regular expression itself, it works fine:

```
$ echo '
/var/lib/mysqlplus
/var/lib/mysql/
/var/lib/mysql
/var/lib/mysql/xyz' | sed -E 's|/var/lib/mysql([$/])|/var/lib/mysql3307\1|'

/var/lib/mysqlplus
/var/lib/mysql3307/
/var/lib/mysql
/var/lib/mysql3307/xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of `$` as a literal character may need to be escaped, but not as an anchor meaning the end of the string.

BTW, your regex would be a lot easier to read if you used a different delimiter, so you didn't have escape the `/` *in* the regex

```
sed -i `'s|/var/lib/mysql/|/var/lib/mysql13307/|' /etc/my.cnf
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to change just the `datadir` value, the following command is more reasonable:
`sed -i.bak 's| *datadir *=.*|datadir = /var/lib/mysql3306/|g' /etc/my.cnf`

Note: `-i.bak` the backup of the original file with suffix `.bak` before making the change.